# Equivalent fillPoly in Tensorflow

Tags: python, opencv, tensorflow

Does the Tensorflow API have a function equivalent to OpenCV [cv2.fillPoly](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#fillpoly) or another one which can draw filled bounding boxes on a black background, [like this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lmjlR.png). In order to  keep only the filled boxes from the original image with an `tf.bitwise_and`. I've already tried with [tf.image.crop_to_bounding_box](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/crop_to_bounding_box), but I need to iterate over my boxes with this function and I can't because the shape is `(None,4)`.

EDIT:
Here a part of my code

```
            res = tf.gather(boxes,true_indices) #My boxes shape (None,4)
            back = tf.get_variable("back", shape=image.shape, dtype=tf.uint8,
                                initializer=tf.zeros_initializer(), trainable=False) #Represent background

                def my_func(x):
                    casted_boxes = tf.cast(x, dtype=tf.int32)
                    casted_img = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(image, dtype=tf.uint8)
                    cropped_image = tf.image.crop_to_bounding_box(casted_img, casted_boxes[1],casted_boxes[0],
                                                              casted_boxes[3] - casted_boxes[1], casted_boxes[2] - casted_boxes[0])
                    return  back[casted_boxes[0]:, casted_boxes[1]:, :].assign(cropped_image) #Here I get a problem
            r = tf.map_fn(my_func, res, tf.uint8)
```

With this code above I get : `AttributeError: 'Operation' object has no attribute '_c_op'`

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Why would TF include image drawing functions..? Why not just use the OpenCV functions?

Comment: Because the shape of the image are set to None until the runtime, because I work this the Dataset API and TFRecords

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure I followed what you mean by iterating over your boxes, so please clarify if I miss your point.

I believe what you need to use is `tf.map_fn` to perform the operation over many boxes. `tf.map_fn` will apply some set of tensorflow operations (which you define by returning them as your map function) to each element in your data.

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/map_fn

In this case your bounding boxes which are of shape `[None, 4]`. At runtime they will have some shape, if you have 42 bounding boxes, for example, that shape would be `[42, 4]`.

`tf.map_fn` in this case would unpack the bounding boxes along the first dimension of 42 bounding boxes and apply whatever OPs you return from the map function to each of them, and return the concatenated result.

Comment: I've tried to use map_fn but I get an error whe I assign the sub tensor (cf. my edit)

Comment: I can't immediately see what to do to fix it, but I believe the use of a variable in the `map_fn` is the root of your problem. You should generate the image the way you want using operations, not variables in `my_func`. That function will be run in parallel after all.